# Extjs best practice of communication between several ViewControllers and Views

Tags: extjs

The question is, how to build a common application using extjs5 where within the west region I have a treepanel and within the center region I want to add panels depending on the treepanel items click. The panels should go in separate files and should have it's own ViewControllers in separate files also. Regions are in a viewport. The viewport has it's own MainViewController.

1. I've tried to get a ViewController from MainViewController, but unfortunately I didn't find the right solution.
2. I've also tried instead of several ViewControllers create common Controllers and call their methods from MainViewController like this:

   MyApp.app.getController('ConnectionController').showPanel();

but i can't get an idea how to get a View from it's Controller - all of the bellow return undefined:

```
console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#connection')[0]);
console.log(Ext.getCmp('connection'));
console.log(this.lookupReference('connection'));
```

After all I decided it is a wrong communication model. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured it out. To make a communication between MainViewController and Panels it is possible to create already defined panel from view controller like this:

```
var panelToAddName = Ext.create('MyApp.view.Panel1View', {});
```